# Работа с файлами в винформс

Tags: visual-c++

Как сравнить 2 файла построчно, и записать строки в 3 файл без повторяющихся слов вот код который есть. не понимаю как сравнить две строки move и move_1 и записать слова из них без повторов в 3 строку а эту строку в 3 файл (как-то так)

```
string move= msclr::interop::marshal_as<string>(textBox3->Text);
string move_1 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<string>(textBox4->Text);
try {
    StreamWriter^ f = gcnew StreamWriter(textBox1->Text,false);
    f->Write(textBox3->Text);
    StreamWriter^ a = gcnew StreamWriter(textBox2->Text, false);
    a->Write(textBox4->Text);
    StreamReader ^ a;
    StreamWriter^ b = gcnew StreamWriter(textBox5->Text, false);

    
    f->Close();
    a->Close();
    b->Close();
```

Comment: `работа с файлами`, `вот код`... это все хорошо...но в чем собственно ваш вопрос? что не получается? в чем трудность? что не понимаете?

Comment: не понимаю как сравнить две строки move и move_1 и записать слова из них без повторов в 3 строку а эту строку в 3 файл (как-то так)

Comment: так и напишите это в вопросе. для этого есть кнопочка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1445138/edit) под вопросом